# How to Execute Stored Procedure in MVC

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I want to Execute the Stored Procedure in My MVC application.

I am using Database First approach & I have created Some stored procedure like::

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TestProcedure]
@parameter1 int
 AS
set @parameter1 = 1
return @parameter1
```

And I am using some code in My MVC action like this::

```
 private CueEntities db = new CueEntities();
     public ActionResult ExecuteProcedure()
            {
                var parameter1=new SqlParameter("parameter1",1);
                var test = db.Database.SqlQuery<CueEntities>("exec TestProcedure @parameter1",parameter1);
                var check=db.TestProcedure(1);
                return Json(test);

            }
```

But I am not able to get the Returned value & can't able to know that wether the Stored procedure is Executed or not.
Please Help me on this ASAP.

Comment: Please Suggest me on this Code that what I should do in this

Comment: To return a value from stored procedure you need to explicitly declare that . Add one more parameter in stored procedure as : @parameter2 int OUT and return the value in this parameter. Then you can make change in application to get this second parameter with parameter direction as output.

Comment: @Deepshikha is right but you should probably also define it in your parameter declaration: `var parameter1=new SqlParameter("parameter1",1){Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput}`

Comment: It doesn't returns the value "1"  ,
It jsut throws exception that "Children could not be eveluated".

Comment: I would import the procedure in to the `edmx` so it can be called like accessing any other entity.

Comment: Please suggest any code related to my code ASAP

Comment: @user2959554, it is somewhat impolite to ask people to suggest code "ASAP".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Executed the Stored Procedure like,
1) For only Input parameters

```
var check=db.TestProcedure(1);
```

2) For Input as well as Output Parameters in Stored Procedures,

```
 public ActionResult GenerateDocumentInvoice(int CompanyID, int UserID, string Documents)
 {
     var Result = new ObjectParameter("Result", new char());
     var exec = db.GenerateInvoice(CompanyID, UserID, Documents, Result);
     return Json(3);
 }
```

where Input Parameters in Stored Procedure are::  `CompanyID, UserID & Documents`
While `Result` is the Output Parameter.

Answer (score 1):

After you import the procedure into your edmx, change your Action method like below:

```
public ActionResult ExecuteProcedure()
{
   using(var  db = new CueEntities())
   {
     var parameter = 1;
     var query =  db.Database.SqlQuery<TestProcedure>("TestProcedure @parameter1", 
                    new  SqlParameter("@parameter1", parameter)).ToList();          
        return Json(query,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);     
    }
}
```